# Furthest Distance You've Successfully Used a Dynamic Mic From?

Tags: sfx, field-recording, gear

Have a fun SFX recording session going down Sunday - Source is going to be about 140 - 150db, about 100m from me.

Definitely bringing some high SPL shotguns, but was considering using a dynamic. The thing about dynamics is that their frequency response tends to get a little wonky after a distance, but the level of the sound tends to "extend" their reach.

What's the furthest you've ever successfully (as in got a good sound out of) used a dynamic mic?

For me, I think it was about 10m, while recording gun shots.

Comment: It's been a while @Colin, welcome back! 

Answer (score 1):

I had some dynamics up (421s) when recording the implosion of tx stadium.  The thing about sounds that are that loud is that no mic will get the sound just right in isolation.  I'd definitely bring a wide variety of mics, and aim some of them *away* from the source.

Comment: Yeah, I'm bringing about 10 - 12 mics. Planning on bringing a 421, source will be about 130 - 140db

Comment: How far were the dynamics from the implosion? 

Comment: A registered SPL of a jet engine is 110dB to 140dB at 100m.  

Comment: i was just oustide the blast zone, so probably 250-300 yards.  run some of those channels without limiters.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Colin,

I didnt have the chance yet to record a high SPL sound in order to use a dynamic mic. I would try to place it as close as I could in order to get the punchy part of the sound. What's the source?

Best regards,
Marco

Comment: F-18 Fighter Jet

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic mics I mostly work with Shure SM-57 & 58, and as they're modeled to reject feedback by heavy use of the proxi-effect one can't really be much more than 20cm away tops with the 57, much less with the 58. 
I have some cheap dynamics that have distance comparing to condensers, but they doesn't really have very much SPL.
As dynamics are much more mechanical in its construction than condensers, I have a sneaking suspicion they need to be less flexible to handle really high SPL.

Answer (score 0):

just throwing this link in as it might be relevant

http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-distance.htm